# Fast way of initallizing a 3d array (C++)

Tags: c++, performance, multidimensional-array, memory-management

In my program, I need do create a large 3d array (~1GB)
I am currently using two for-loops to init the array:

```
float*** array = new float** [m_width];

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_width; i++)
{
    array3d[i] = new float * [m_height];
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < m_height; j++)
    {
        array3d[i][j] = new float[m_layers];
    }
}
```

The code works fine, but gets very slow.
So my question is: Is there a faster way of initializing/reserving memory for a multi-dimensional array? (A 1d array can be created almost instantly)

Comment: Could you please quantify "very slow"?

Comment: Keep a flat array (1d) and calculate the dimensions for accessing specific elements at their indices.

Comment: That isn't a 3d array. It' an array of pointers to array of pointers to array of float.

Comment: Why not use `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<float> > > array(std::vector<std::vector<float> >(std::vector<float>(m_layers), m_height), m_width);` ????   No need to worry about forgetting to deallocate either - it'll happen implicitly when `array` passes out of scope.

Comment: Fun fact: the innermost arrays are *not* initialized.

Comment: Allocate the memory as a large, single chunk of `width * height * depth`.  If you need it zeroed out (or init'd to value), then use `memset`.  Then index as 3d array.

Comment: @Peter That would have the same drawbacks by means of performance and efficiency.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not creating a 3D array. You're creating a 1D array of pointers, each pointing to a 1D array of pointers, each pointing to a 1D array of `float`s. That's something totally different with respect to allocation efficiency, cache locality, access efficiency etc.

It'll be much more efficient if you instead create just one array of size `width * height * depth`, and use index arithmetic to access it. And remember that the standard way of spelling "dynamic array" in C++ is `std::vector`; this is especially relevant for you since `vector` value-initialises all of its elements (which for `float` means initialising them to `.0f`). You can easily create something like this:

```
class Array3d
{
  size_t height, depth;
  std::vector<float> data;

public:
  Array3d(size_t width, size_t height, size_t depth) :
    height(height),
    depth(depth),
    data(width * height * depth)
  {}

  float& at(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z)
  { return data[x * height * depth + y * depth + z]; }

  float at(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z) const
  { return data[x * height * depth + y * depth + z]; }
};
```

Add more functions, safety checks etc. to taste.

Reasons why this is much faster:

- On allocation: this is just one call to the (rather expensive) dynamic allocation mechanism, instead of the `width * height + height + 1` calls in the question.
- On access: This requires a few integer operations and one pointer dereference to get to any data member. The separate-arrays mechanism requires 3 sequential memory fetches (compute and offset, retrieve pointer there, offset it, retrieve another pointer, ...).

Answer (score 1):

An approach I am doing when I want to avoid multidimensional array initialization but want a multidimensional array access is this:

```
#define IDX_3D(x, y, z, width, height) ((x) + (y) * (width) + (z) * (width) * (height))

void main()
{
    int width, height, depth;
    width = height = depth = 2;
    float* multi_array = new float[width * height * depth];

    multi_array[IDX_3D(1, 1, 1, width, height)] = 1.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since C++11 you can use the following code:

```
int array[5][5][5] = {0};
```

This will create a 3d array with 125 integers filled with zeros.
IMHO this is the fastest (in terms of lines of code) way to create and initalize a 3d array on the stack.

To create one on the heap (with new) the other answers seems to be good.

Of course you have to fill it with your data afterwards which will take some time, but it should be aceptable fast.

Comment: This requires the size to be known at compile time.

Comment: Please note that the OP needs to create a *"a large 3d array (~1GB)"*.

Answer (score 0):

I think in two options:

1. Load a file with array structure.
2. Use Threads to initializing, this form could use more cpu in initializing.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer said, this is not a "block" array but a bunch of allocated pointers to pointers to allocated memory.
You spend a lot of time (N^2) allocating elements and another bunch of time allocating arrays of pointers.
This is the price you pay for having the freedom to have "rows" with different sizes but this is something you don't need in the first place apparently.

There is a famous article about it [Dynamic Arrays in C—The Wrong Way](https://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Dynamic-Arrays-in-C_002dThe-Wrong-Way.html).

As the other answer says you need to allocate a single block of memory and access it in strides.

A sane alternative is to use a library that does this for you.
The are many libraries out there, one is [Multi](https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi) (disclaimer, I am the author).

Your code will reduce to this:

```
multi::array<float, 3> arr({m_width, m_height, m_layers});
```

(add a value as last argument to initialize to a well defined value.)

Fortunately, you can still *access the elements* with the same syntax you use with your code, e.g. `arr[1][2][3]`.

full code: https://godbolt.org/z/fT1E7YbPG